# Java Swing GridBagLayout() Spanning an object 3 lines doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have a GridBagLayout 5 lines per 5 columns. I'm trying to span my first object which is a TilePanel on the 3 lines and 5 columns. It' partially working.

I have line 4 and 5 with object. I would expect the first 3 lines would take more space then line 4 and 5. Actually, the space is equally splited onto the Window. What am I doing wrong? See code snippet below and screenshot:

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints();


// Initialize all the UI components
tilePanel = new TilePanel(gameModel);

grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

// Grid 5 lines by 5 columns
grid.weightx = 5;
grid.weighty = 5;

// tilePanel takes 3 lines and 5 columns
grid.gridwidth = 5;
grid.gridheight = 3;
grid.gridx = 0;
grid.gridy = 0;
this.add(tilePanel, grid);

// Forth Line       
goal = new JLabel("Goal: " + gameModel.getGameResult());
currentSum = new JLabel("Current sum: 0");
nextButton = new JButton("NEXT");
resetButton = new JButton("RESET");

grid.gridwidth = 1;
grid.gridheight = 1; 

// Forth Line: First column
grid.gridy = 4;
grid.gridx = 0;     
this.add(nextButton, grid);

// Forth Line: Second column
grid.gridx = 1;
this.add(resetButton, grid);


// Firth Line
grid.gridy = 5;

// Firth Line: First column
grid.gridx = 0;
goal.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
this.add(goal, grid);

// Firth Line: Second column
grid.gridx = 1;
currentSum.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
this.add(currentSum, grid);

// Firth Line: Third column
grid.gridx = 2;
this.add(new JLabel("TIME"), grid);     

// Firth Line: Fourth column
grid.gridx = 3;
this.add(new JLabel("RESET"), grid);    

// Firth Line: Fifth column
grid.gridx = 4;
this.add(new JLabel("LEVEL"), grid);
```

Screenshot of Window:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xngBG.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

weightx and weighty should be float values, with minimum in 0.0 and maximun in 1.0. Value 1.0 means "get as much space as you can", and 0.0 means "you are the last one to get extra space". You give values of 5, and probably the GridBagLayout is making... whatever it makes.

I would try to set the weigthx to 1.0 and weighty=0.6 (60% of the vertical space) when adding tilePanel and weighty=0.2 when adding the rest (20% of vertical space each row).

But I haven't tested it.

Comment: Yeah right!! It's working fine! Thanks for explaining. The documentation is not so clear about parameters and it's a nightmare. You made my day!

Comment: `weighty` is only for "extra" space. When you pack() the frame each row will be displayed at its preferred height.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to span my first object which is a TilePanel on the 3 lines

You can't just say a component spans 3 lines.

The height of any given line is determined by the height of the components added to that line. If you don't add a component to a line, then that line has no height.

In your example you add components with a `gridy` of 0, 4, 5. So there are no components in `gridy` of 1, 2, 3 so each of those grids has a 0 height.

You can only span rows if you have components in each of the rows. So if you had 5 components added with a `gridy` of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, then you could add a 6th component (to another column) with a `gridy` of 0, with a `gridheight` of 3. Then this component would have a height equal to the height of the components in gridy 0, 1 and 2.

If you want the first row to be larger, then maybe you can use the `ipady` value to give the title panel extra space. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information about all the constraints and a working example.